# Swift.org issue with open source swift project. Error: xcrun: error: unable to find utility "launch-with-toolchain", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, xcrun

I am trying to Start Xcode with the custom toolchain and to be  enabled to use the open source version of Swift.

Steps are taken from [Swift.org](https://swift.org/download/#apple-platforms)

And I receive this error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "launch-with-toolchain", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Comment: With what parameters did you call xcrun? Do you have the latest Xcode 7.2 installed on El Capitan?

Comment: Yes i am using latest El Capitan and two Xcode 7.2 and Xcode 6.4

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't work for me either, `xcrun launch-with-toolchain /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain` produces the same error.

Comment: @EricD.: Would you mind to check if the solution works for you as well?

Comment: @MartinR Done. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The open source Swift toolchain from https://swift.org/download/#apple-platforms requires the latest Xcode 7.2 (currently: beta 4).

The location of the developer directory used by `xcrun` and other build tools must be set to this Xcode 7.2. This can be done from the command-line
with

```
sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/Xcode7.2-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

or in the Xcode "Locations" preferences:

[image]

Comment: thx for quick response problem was in the issue that you describe. Thx for that!

Comment: This fixed my issue, Why it's not atomically selects the latest or at least one of them?