# SwiftXCTest not found

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xctest

When trying to run Swift Foundation library tests (TestFoundation) from XCode, XCode says that it cannot import SwiftXCTest (No Such Module 'SwiftXCTest').

Note that I am able to build new swift runtime using 2.2 swift so the tools are properly installed, and I am running xcode properly from command line using

```
 xcrun launch-with-toolchain /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain
```

on Xcode 7.2 Beta 4 ; El Capitan

Is there anything else that needs to be done in order to properly run tests?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089153/swift-org-issue-with-open-source-swift-project-error-xcrun-error-unable-to-f just look probably same

Comment: No, this is not the same. As I noted, I can actually run build tools (which is their primary problem) - I can run the xcode and everything looks good - it is just I cannot run the test suite :) Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for everyone - I resolved my problem and I am posting it here as answer because I believe I won't be the only one. I forgot to run build-script that is provided with swift repository. Oh well.

For future reference, here is [full guide](https://github.com/yep/swift-build) that needs to be done in order to have everything working, step-by-step.

Just run everything in right order and you should be golden.