# Posdpec validation Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I tried to submit my first cocoapod and I typed:

```
pod trunk push MyLib.podspec
```

following error occurs:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (/usr/bin/xcrun simctl list devices

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH) during validation.
```

I have tried to find solution but without good results

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089153/swift-org-issue-with-open-source-swift-project-error-xcrun-error-unable-to-f